# convert Request.Form from classic ASP to ASP.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, inline-code

i am converting a Asp classic project to asp.net i get line of code, i stuck how to convert this code to ASP.NET 2010 . I am doing inline coding in ASP.NET

**ASP Classic**

```
 if request.form <> "" then
SQL = "UPDATE TBL_SPACES set pass_option='"&encode(request.form("pass_option"))&"' where parker_id="&encode(request.Cookies("parker")("id"))&""
'response.write(SQL)
Connection.Execute(SQL)
connection.close
set connection=nothing
response.redirect("/parker/")
end if
```

**ASP.NET**

```
 If Not Request.Form Is Nothing Then
    SQL = "UPDATE TBL_SPACES set pass_option='" & encode(Request.Form("pass_option")) & "' where parker_id=" & encode(Request.Cookies("parker").Values("id")) & ""
    'response.write(SQL)

    Dim Query As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(SQL, connection)
    rs = Query.ExecuteReader()
    connection.Close()
    connection = Nothing
    Response.Redirect("/parker/")
End If
```

but when the redirect to this page this event always fire and update the database .

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `if request.form <> ""` relates to `If Not Page.IsPostBack`

So in your example the SQL is run once on initial page load.